# Inequality counterparts of `\asymp`

Tags: symbols, characters

I would like to have inequality-type symbols corresponding to `\asymp` [image].

I have tried

```
\newcommand{\ffrown}{\text{\raisebox{3pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\frown$}}}
\renewcommand{\O}{\underset{\ffrown}{<}}
\newcommand{\OG}{\underset{\ffrown}{>}}
```

and got [image] and [image], but these two do not seem to match quite well with [image].

Are there better solutions?

Comment: What do you want it to mean? (Are the amsmath  `\succcurlyeq` and `\preccurlyeq` and `\curlyeqprec` and `\curlyeqsucc` suitable?)

Comment: @WillieWong : Thank you for these suggestions. However, they do not seem to match quite well with `\asymp`. I want a `symbol` such that "A`symbol`B" means "A=O(B)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a clipped `\asymp` symbol and then stack `<` or `>` above it.

The symbol will automatically scale in subscripts or superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lasymp}{\lg@asymp{<}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gasymp}{\lg@asymp{>}}

\newcommand{\under@asymp}[1]{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt {0.5\height}}{$\m@th#1\asymp$}}
\newcommand{\lg@asymp}[1]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\lg@asymp@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lg@asymp@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \m@th
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      $#1#2$\cr
      \under@asymp{#1}\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \lasymp b \asymp c \gasymp d$

$\scriptstyle a \lasymp b \asymp c \gasymp d$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a perfect solution.